# asm instruction syntax and programming syntax in general

Tags: syntax, command, arguments

What do you call the notation used to describe the syntax for assembler instructions? Let me clarify, take for example the add instruction. It says the syntax for add is

> ADD{ S } Rd, Rn, <Operand2>

what is this notation used to describe operation syntax called? what can I search/where can I look to learn more about this notation? Furthermore how can I learn about the notation used to describe the syntax of other languages such as c, java, bash commands etc? I would imagine their is a name for such a thing but its hard to find information with the lack of my vocabulary...